# Escape "@" character in Android

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to escape the "@" symbol at the start of a string, in Android strings.xml resource. I'm continuously getting compilation errors and the layout builder in Eclipse refuses to work :(. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 7):

The character scape depends of each one, the android documentation provides this table in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On the Android Documentation website, it says to use a double backslash to escape characters.

< string name="twitter">\\@mytwitter< /string>

Comment: It's helpful to point to the actual documentation when referencing it

Answer (score 3):

You should use the "\" before "@". eg

```
escaped\@
```

:-)

Comment: If I put <string name="twitter">\@mytwitter</string>, I still have a compilation error. Do you have another workaround?

Comment: I just tried your string in my strings.xml , it works , whats the exact error you are getting?

Comment: No more compilation errors. However, it displays the backslash character. I got something working with <string name="twitter">\ @mytwitter</string> (a space between "\" and "@"). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling), you'll have to escape certain characters with a backslash `\` or enclosing the whole string with double quotes `" "`. Only if the string starts with `@`, it has to be escaped.

Backslash:
`<string name="twitter">\@user</string>`
`<string name="email">user@domain</string>`

Double quotes:
`<string name="twitter">"@user"</string>`
`<string name="email">user@domain</string>`

Other characters that needs to be escaped are `< > & ' " ?`

Answer (score 1):

Space between backslash and slash worked for me, thx!
    `<string name="first">1\ /4</string>`