# Android Xml - How do you write '@' character in the string?

Tags: android, xml, string

I'm trying to write email address with @ character inside the xml using TextView. I tried using Unicode like someone suggested in the other post asking about '&' character. It didn't work for @. I tried

```
<string name="gmail">\u0040 gmail.com</string>
```

but that returns java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I also tried

```
<string name="gmail" formatted="false">@gmail.com</string>
```

but it still gives the same error.

I have no idea how to go about this problem. 
Please Help!!

Comment: have you tried `\@gmail.com` or `&#64;gmail.com`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063309/escape-character-in-android - (which points you to http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2219 - a very good explanation).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<string name="gmail">\@ gmail.com</string>
```

@ is, of course, the way you reference identified resources (@+id\textview) which requires escaping to use.

Pretty sure that formatted="false" does not flag Android to avoid looking up identifiers.